# Successful dereference seems to cause a latent segfault

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, dereference

As mentioned in the title, I'm successfully dereferencing the data coming to and from the **modMYSTRUCT** and **showMeThis** functions. The proper output before "**Fourth check**" displays but a segfault occurs:

```
First check
Second check
0
Third check
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This doesn't happen, however, when I comment from ( `cout << "First check\n";` to `cout << "Third check\n";` ) or from ( `MYSTRUCT struct_inst;` to `cout << "Fourth check\n";` ). When I do so, the code produces the expected output for the uncommented code.

The afformentioned code producing the segfault:

```cpp
struct MYSTRUCT
{
  int * num;
};

void modMYSTRUCT( MYSTRUCT * struct_inst )
{
  cout << *(struct_inst->num) << endl;
  *(struct_inst->num) = 2;
}

int showMeThis( int * x )
{
  return *x;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "First check\n";
  int x[1][1] = { {0} };
  cout << "Second check\n";
  cout << showMeThis(&(**x)) << endl;
  cout << "Third check\n";


  MYSTRUCT struct_inst;
  *(struct_inst.num) = 1;
  modMYSTRUCT(&struct_inst);

  cout << *(struct_inst.num) << endl;
  cout << "Fourth check\n";
}
```

I'm clueless here. For context, I was looking for a better way to dereference GLM matrices. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try stepping through a debugger?

Comment: `struct_inst.num` is never initialized so your program has Undefined Behavior. That means that it might work, or might work inconsistently, or might not work at all.

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to accomplish? It is a toy example, but what is the goal of the toy? Start at a high level, work your way down to more details, and [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why there cannot be an error in your code. Be sure to imagine your duck looking at you doubtfully after each explanation. ;)

Comment: Just now and unlike in regular compilation, it produced a segfault when commenting from `cout << "First check\n";` to `cout << "Third check\n";`.

Comment: @JaMiT It's an experiment at passing the address of single elements from double buffered arrays ( I'm also aware now, that `&(**x)` is kind of redundant unless I'm referring to an element at any index besides the first of each dimension of the array ). Luckily, the debugger and @1201ProgramAlarm brought the initialization of `struct_inst.num` to mind. I see now that I'm assigning a value to an unallocated region of memory. Why this consistently causes segfaults in the previously described way? `¯\_(-_-)_/¯` ...Like @1201ProgramAlarm said, "inconsistency".

Comment: @Texedo The purpose of the experiment is why you wrote the code, not what the code does. You can start with the purpose, but then work down to a more detailed explanation. For example, explain the role of the array and structure in `main()`. Keep working down to more detailed explanations until you can state why each line of your code is undeniably correct. See [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for why this can be a useful exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `MYSTRUCT` with this:

```
struct MYSTRUCT
{
  int * num;                    
  MYSTRUCT() {num = new int;}   // allocate memory for an integer
  ~MYSTRUCT() {delete num;}     // free memory (will be called when struct_inst goes out of scope)
};
```

But honestly, just because you can do this, doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: So, what's the issue with this? If the context goes out of scope of the function where struct_inst is declared, it's normal for it to be deleted, right?

Comment: That does the trick. I guess the other option would be to point to a previously assigned int or use malloc().

Comment: Sorry, I see the problem with it, now. An out of scope function could still try to access it by reference. If only I could edit my comment.

Comment: @Texedo, The reason I said you shouldn't is because there is no real reason to use a pointer to an integer there instead of just a simple `int num`. Also, for your specific example, when `struct_inst` goes out of scope, the pointer to the integer is cleared, but the integer is not, so it's a memory leak.

Comment: The purpose of pointers to int(s) was to simulate the GLM mat4 type, which, to my understanding, acts as a 2D array of floats. This was an experiment with the emulated mat4, to find a better syntax for passing the address of the first element of the matrix. I just happened to gloss over the shoddy assignment ( or lack thereof ) of the first element.